# How to bind AmCharts (Stock Chart) to select all the datasets?

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amstock

In my StockChart I want to select all datasets but it just binds the first dataset item (Anadolu YK).

How can I do to select others?
(Avrupa YK)
(Bursa)
(Antalya)
..

[JsFiddle Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/Lhka8Lb4/)

```
 dataSets: [{
            title: "Anadolu YK",
            fieldMappings: [{
                fromField: "value",
                toField: "value"
            }, {
                fromField: "volume",
                toField: "volume"
            }],
            dataProvider: chartData1,
            categoryField: "date"
        },

          {
              title: "Avrupa YK",
              fieldMappings: [{
                  fromField: "value",
                  toField: "value"
              }, {
                  fromField: "volume",
                  toField: "volume"
              }],
              dataProvider: chartData2,
              categoryField: "date"
          },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a Data Set pre-selected set its [`compared`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/DataSet#compared) property to `true`:

```
{
  title: "Avrupa YK",
  fieldMappings: [ {
    fromField: "value",
    toField: "value"
  }, {
    fromField: "volume",
    toField: "volume"
  } ],
  dataProvider: chartData2,
  categoryField: "date",
  compared: true
}
```

Comment: Thank you, saved my time. Sorry my reputation is low and i can't mark as answer.

Comment: You can't upvote answer, but can surely accept an answer to your question, because otherwise what would be the point of being allow to ask questions ;)